# PHP looping, incrementing variable names

Tags: php, html, loops, variables

I have to create a 'receipts' table which consists of 10 columns and 15 rows. What I do in row 1 is basically what I have to do until row 15 (and I already have a long block of code!).
I can simply redo the code fifteen times, but I would like to know if it possible to just loop, and if so, how do i do it.

**I want my whole code repeated 15 times, with the text input RECEIPTDATA1 and button SAVEBUTTON1 also incrementing (i.e. becomes RECEIPTDATA2 and SAVEBUTTON2 at the next loop... RECEIPTDATA3 and SAVEBUTTON3 the next... until RECEIPTDATA15 and SAVEBUTTON15)**

I am still very new in learning php. I hope to learn from you. Thanks in advance.

//validation part of code

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['SAVEBUTTON1'])){
   $sdp = array();

       function test_input($data) {
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    return $data;}

  if     ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST") {
    if(empty($_POST["RECEIPTDATA1"]))
            {$sdp[0]="*";}
    else
            { $sdp[0] =     test_input($_POST["RECEIPTDATA1"]); }
?>
```

//interface part of code

```
<?php
if ($editrec01=="1") {
?>

<form method="post" action="<?php echo 'http://localhost:90/spcs/doregreq.php?id='.$row['formdata'].';'?>">

<tr><td>

<input type="text" class="shwt" name="RECEIPTDATA1" value="<?php echo (isset($_POST["RECEIPTDATA1"]) ? $_POST["RECEIPTDATA1"] : '');?>" placeholder="">

<span class="error"><?php if(isset($_POST['SAVEBUTTON1'])){echo strpbrk("$sdp[0]","*");}?></span>

</td>

<td>
<button type="submit" class="btnclk" name="SAVEBUTTON1">Save</button>
<button type="submit" class="btnclk" name="cancel">Close</button>

</td></tr>

</form>

<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: What is your desired output and which lines are you duplicating 15 times?

Comment: I need to have the whole code I posted repeated 15 times, with the variables (text input and button names) incrementing as well. (i.e. orno1, datd1, amtd1,datp1, amtp1 etc... becoming orno2, datd2, amtp2 etc. until orno15.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way to loop one of your tds. Note the $_POST arrays are stubbed. Flavor to your needs:

```
$aEntry1 = array();
$aEntry1[ 'rmrx1' ] = 1;
$aEntry1[ 'actn1' ] = 1;
$aEntry1[ 'random1' ] = 'abc';
$aEntry1[ 'random2' ] = 'defg';

$aEntry2 = array();
$aEntry2[ 'rmrx1' ] = 2;
$aEntry2[ 'actn1' ] = 2;
$aEntry2[ 'random1' ] = 'defaga';
$aEntry2[ 'random2' ] = 'zyzx';

$_POST[] = $aEntry1;
$_POST[] = $aEntry2;

$iCountData = count( $_POST );
for( $i = 0; $i < $iCountData; ++$i )
{
    $sEntry  = '';
    $sEntry .= '<td>';
    $sEntry .= '<input type="text" class="shwt" name="';
    $sEntry .= $_POST[ $i ][ 'rmrx1' ];
    $sEntry .= '" value="';
    $sEntry .= ( empty( $_POST[ $i ][ 'rmrx1' ] ) ? '' : $_POST[ $i ][ 'rmrx1' ] );
    $sEntry .= '" placeholder="';
    $sEntry .= 'Some placeholder? Or loop data: ';
    $sEntry .= $_POST[ $i ][ 'random1' ];
    $sEntry .= '">';
    $sEntry .= '<span class="error">';
    $sEntry .= ( empty( $_POST[ $i ][ 'actn1' ] ) ? '' : $_POST[ $i ][ 'actn1' ] ); // Or strpbrk("$sdp[7]","*");
    $sEntry .= '</span>';
    $sEntry .= '</td>';
    echo $sEntry;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm kind of expecting I would do something that loops the whole thing, which includes some code like RECEIPTDATA.(increment) ?